# Infinite AnimatorSet memory/process issue

Tags: android

I am struggling with what I think is a huge bug in the OS here. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have an activity with a **simple infinite AnimatorSet animation** on a view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="0.3"
        android:valueTo="1.0" />
</set>
```

This animation basically **fades the view in and out sequentially**. The animation works.

In the activity's onDestroy() method, I end the animation using animation.end().

What happens is, **even when the activity is destroyed, the app's process still uses processor time** :

[image: Process list]

This makes no sense, as the activity is closed.

I have tested this again and again, and removing the AnimatorSet fixes that.

I have also tried several different methods for removing the AnimatorSet : animation.end(), animation.cancel(), animation = null

What do you guys think ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using this wrong :

**What I did :**

```
onCreate(){
    animation = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.animation);
    animation.setTarget(myView);
    animation.start();
}

onDestroy(){
    if(animation != null){
        animation.cancel();
    }
}

onPause(){
    if(animation != null){
        animation.end();
    }
}

onResume(){
    if(animation != null){
        animation.start();
    }
}
```

**What fixed this :**

```
onCreate(){
    animation = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.animation);
    animation.setTarget(myView);
    animation.start();
}

onDestroy(){
    if(animation != null){
        animation.cancel();
    }
}

onPause(){
    if(animation != null && animation.isStarted()){
        animation.end();
    }
}

onResume(){
    if(animation != null && !animation.isStarted()){
        animation.start();
    }
}
```